# How to stop executing else part after breaking loop in if statement in angular 8?

Tags: typescript, angular8

My requirement here is I have a array as follows,

```
{"OPN":0,"INPR":8,"WAIT":2,"STP":1,"RED":13}
```

I want to display a modal window if count of all keys except WAIT is 0,
if count of all keys is greater than 0 then I want to display another modal window.
 I tried something like this but this is failing, as it showing both the modal windows.

```
 for (let index = 0; index <  this.status.length; index++) {
            if(this.status[index] != 'WAIT' && this.countOfStatus[this.status[index]] > 0){
              $("#modal1").modal("show");
              break;
            }else{
              dummyVar = true;
            }
          }
          if(dummyVar){
             $("#modal2").modal("show");
          }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Angular. You're actually using JQuery, BTW, which is not such a good idea, in an Angular application. It's a pure JavaScript/TypeScript question.

You want to display a single modal. So the code displaying the modal shouldn't be in the loop.

My advice would be to use simpler functions, doing one thing:

1. A function which returns the modal to show
2. A function which displays the modal

.

```
findIdOfModalToShow(): string {
  for (let index = 0; index <  this.status.length; index++) {
    if (this.status[index] != 'WAIT' && this.countOfStatus[this.status[index]] > 0) {
      return 'modal1';
    }
  }
  return 'modal2';
}

showAppropriateModal() {
  const idOfModalToShow = this.findIdOfModalToShow();
  $(`#${idOfModalToShow}`).modal('show');
}
```